# Angular Change Detection does not work properly - Angular16

Tags: angular, angular-binding

I start working in a new angular project, I find such a weird behavior that we can see throw the following example

```js
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.test = 100
      console.log('changed value .. ' + this.test)
      // this.crf.detectChanges();
    }, 3000)
}
```

```html
<div>test {{test}}</div>
<button (click)="clickTest()">test</button>
```

the value **test** is not changed by the **Timeout** ( we have to add `this.crf.detectChanges()` to do so )

when we click on the button it changes as well. I've already take a look to the [documentation](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)  But I'm not able to figure out the reasons for such behavior ! and How can we fix it ?

Comment: Are you in a zoneless app ? Can you provide a stackblitz repro of that issue ?

Comment: a `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` makes this: only when input, or button or Observable subscribe (with async pipe or in code) Angular automaticaly "refresh". Check this [link related](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

Comment: See that, if you have a button and click, Angular repaint with the actual value of the "test". check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j8264x?file=src%2Fmain.ts). If after 3 seconds you chick the button "fool" the value of the test "magically apear". If you instead call to the button "doit" Angular repain the actual value of test, but, after 3 seconds not change, if you click "doit with detect", change.